# btn-xs no longer a valid option in bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I just migrated to bootstrap 4 and my xs buttons no longer seem to be extra small!

Looking at the [docs for buttons in bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/) I don't see the option for extra small buttons?

Can anyone confirm this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: As you stated from the [Docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#sizes) and if you check the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css), nope.

Comment: @vanburen, I guess I can just write my own css class called .btn-xs then aye

Answer (score 112):

[@rifton007](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21881#issuecomment-341972830) posted a quick fix in the GitHub issue on this subject. Add this in your css file:

```
.btn-group-xs > .btn, .btn-xs {
  padding: .25rem .4rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: .5;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}
```

Demo:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.btn-group-xs > .btn, .btn-xs {
  padding: .25rem .4rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: .5;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}
</style>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">♡</button>
```

[source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21881#issuecomment-341972830)

Edit:

later on the issue, [@deadmann](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21881#issuecomment-609382122) replied that he dig up a little in old BS3 documentation and extract the following code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.btn-group-xs > .btn, .btn-xs {
padding: 1px 5px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.5;
border-radius: 3px;
}
</style>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">♡</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">♡</button>
```

Comment: **+1** for Referencing the Original Source-Link and giving **Rifton007** his due credit.  In the Source-Link **Squadwuschel** made an excellent point about how not everyone of us are writing responsive mobile apps and how sometimes you just want to slip a Button in a Grid for a Desktop experience that doesn't over-expand every row it is in.

Comment: .btn-group-xs > .btn, .btn-xs {
 padding: 0.40rem .4rem;
 font-size: .775rem;
 line-height: .5;
 border-radius: .2rem;
}

Comment: Yes, like @MikeTeeVee said, "sometimes you just want to slip a Button in a Grid for a Desktop experience that doesn't over-expand every row it is in". That's the big one. What were they thinking?

Comment: Validated as working with Bootsrap 5, thanks! i used this class example for a button group which worked nicely, but also I added "w-100" to the button group class which ensures that the button group expands to the full width of the parent div so it alligns up nicely.

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is no `btn-xs` in Bootstrap 4, you will have to create this class your self. In the `scss/mixins/_buttons.scss` you will find the mixin called `button-size` so in you SCSS code use the following code:

```
.btn-xs {
  // line-height: ensure proper height of button next to extra small input 
  @include button-size($padding-y, $padding-x, $font-size, $line-height, $border-radius);
}
```

Comment: can you provide css?

Comment: button-size() is no longer a valid function.

Comment: button-size is still valid: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss#L99

Comment: Is it recommended to edit files that come directly from bootstrap? That is files with the prefix underscore ( _ ).

Answer (score 13):

you need to define your own xs style and variable this matches best for me and comes close to the bootstrap 3 btn-xs size:

**Bootstrap 4 Alpha**

```
$btn-padding-x-xs: .38rem !default;
$btn-padding-y-xs: .18rem !default;

.btn-xs {
    @include button-size($btn-padding-y-xs, $btn-padding-x-xs, $font-size-sm, $btn-border-radius-sm);
}
```

**Bootstrap 4 Beta 2**

```
$btn-padding-x-xs:  .20rem !default;
$btn-padding-y-xs:  .12rem !default;
$input-btn-line-height-xs: 1.1 !default;

.btn.btn-xs {
   // line-height: ensure proper height of button next to small input
   @include button-size($btn-padding-y-xs, $btn-padding-x-xs, $font-size-sm, $input-btn-line-height-xs, $btn-border-radius-sm);
}
```

Comment: There is a new (in Beta 2) `$line-height` argument. Now use: `@include button-size($btn-padding-y-xs, $btn-padding-x-xs, $font-size-sm, $input-btn-line-height-sm, $btn-border-radius-sm);`

Comment: can you provide css ?

Comment: button-size() is no longer a valid function.

Comment: button-size is still valid: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss#L99

Comment: Yeah I realized that a few hours later. Should update the answer to mention that mixin must be manually loaded before your vars to work.

Comment: Is it recommended to edit files that come directly from bootstrap? That is files with the prefix underscore ( _ ).

Answer (score 7):

I have extracted CSS from the Old Version of Bootstrap. You can use the below mentioned CSS style in your custom stylesheet. With the help of class named btn-xs, you can use the old style for your button.

Good Luck.

```css
button
{
  margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.btn-xs
{
    padding: 1px 5px !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.5 !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">This is Small Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

I added this as Bass Jobsen suggested:

```
.btn-xs
  +button-size($btn-padding-y-sm, $btn-padding-x-sm, $font-size-sm, $line-height, $border-radius)
```

Using the default `_variables.scss` of Bootstrap and this was the result:

[image: btn-xs]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: button-size() is no longer a valid function.

Comment: normally it is:

Main repo: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss#L99

Ruby repo: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss#L99

Comment: Yeah I realized that a few hours later. Should update the answer to mention that mixin must be manually loaded before your vars to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer available the option of extra small button in bootstrap 4.
Only 3 sizes are available, large, normal, small.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Bootstrap 5

```
.btn-xs {
    @include button-size($btn-padding-y-xs, $btn-padding-x-xs, $font-size-xs, $border-radius);
}
```